# What level do you start receiving gifts at?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

I'm level 32 at the moment and was wondering what level you start to receive gifts.

Comment: If my answer has answered your question, you should mark it as accepted in case anyone else has this question.

Answer (score 4):

Receiving gifts is not dependent on player level. Gifts are sent by people who have added you to their friends list. They are able to send gifts (it sends to all of their friends) once every 21 hours.